# Rails: Javascript does not work on paginated objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, pagination, infinite-scroll

I followed Ryan Bates [Railscast #114(revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page-revised?view=comments), and added endless scrolling to my page. Javascript works on the initial first ten objects (the first ten objects that is loaded when the site is loaded), but the problem is that javascript does not work on the rest of the objects that is loaded when I scroll (the paginated objects).

Does someone know how I can solve this problem?

**.js (this is a dummy js example just to illustrate: there will be borders on the first ten objects, but not the rest)**

```
$ ->
  $(".thumbnail").css "border-width": "2px"
```

**.css**

```
.thumbnail {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ee2a7c;
    border-width: 0px;
}
```

**main_view.html.erb**

```
<div class="container" id="sp">
   <%= render 'pages/singlePost' %>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="span6 offset3">
      <%= will_paginate @posts %>
   </div>
</div>
```

**_singlePost.html.erb**

```
<% @posts.each do |p| %>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="span6 offset3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
           <%= p.title %>
            /*Some other code goes in here*/
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

**main_view.js.erb**

```
$('#sp').append("<%= j render 'pages/singlePost' %>");
<% if @posts.next_page %>
    $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@posts) %>');
<% else %>
    $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

**controller.rb (ten objects are paginated at the time)**

```
def lelist
   @post = Post.new
   @posts = Post.where("DATETIME(created_at) <= DATETIME(?)", Time.now).order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because javascript is loaded an executed on page load, if the elements don't exist when the javascript is executed they obviously won't be subjected to it.

I assume your example is fabricated, because you certainly don't need to, and shouldn't, use javascript to apply CSS in that way.

If you want to attach events to elements which may exist in the future look at using event delegation with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). For example:

```
$('body').on('click', '#some_element', function() {
  // ...
});
```

If you want do some other stuff, put it in a function and make sure you execute the function every time you load new data. For example:

```
var doSomeStuffWhenDataLoads = function() {
  // do whatever you want to do, apply your CSS or whatever.
}
// do it on page load.
doSomeStuffWhenDataLoads();

// ...
$.ajax({
  // ...
  success: function() {
    // insert your new data to the page
    doSomeStuffWhenDataLoads();
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your answer. The example was made up just to illustrate. But how can I use jQuery to check if new elements is added(how can I "put it in a function and make sure you execute the function every time you load new data")?

Comment: edited my answer to include contrived examples, but it's not exactly complicated stuff.